# Python - how to show useful error on failed import

Tags: python, python-import, importerror

**Some background:** I am revamping the package we use in my company as the code base for many projects. This is an internal package, and is used/developed by a very limited number of people, so we allow ourselves to sometimes make major changes without a proper deprecation protocol.

**The problem at hand:** I am removing a few modules from the package as part of the code revamp. These contain some old classes and functions, which are no longer used in new projects. Just in case someone will ever need these objects, perhaps running some old notebook, I would like to move these modules to a different "legacy" package. When someone attempts to import a now-deleted module in the main package, instead of the standard `ImportError`, I would like to be able to give a useful error message instructing them to import from the legacy package. Is there any way to achieve this? Perhaps using the `__init__.py` file?

Comment: There are a number of deprecation libraries which will do what you want, e.g. https://pypi.org/project/deprecation/  https://pypi.org/project/deprecated/

Comment: I am using deprecation warnings elsewhere in the package, but I believe this is a different case - the modules/classes/functions discussed here are being *removed* from the package, so they cannot be deprecated e.g. using a decorator.

Comment: Put the following at the top of the package: `raise DeprecationWarning("Use this module instead")`?